# Async test fails to assert response body

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I can't explain why my test passed although the HTTP status code differs from the expected value.

Here is the test:

```
describe("Test", (): void => {  
    test(`${prefix}` + ": fake field",
    async (): Promise<void> => {
    const stakingRequest : StakingRequest = new StakingRequest(address, address, address, address, amount, "TestField");
        console.log("Request:" + JSON.stringify(stakingRequest))
        console.log("Endpoint:" + `${config.api.path}${EndPoint.STAKE}`)

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, wait));

        await instance.post(`${config.api.path}${EndPoint.STAKE}`, stakingRequest.createRequest())
        .then(
            r => {
                console.log("Response:");
                console.log(r.data);
                console.log(r.status);
                console.log(r.statusText);
                expect(r. status).toBe(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); //actual result HttpStatusCode.OK
            }
        ).catch(error => {
            if (error.response) {
                expect(error.response).toBe("")
            }
        })
}, timeout);
});
```

The problem is that the request returns `HttpStatusCode.OK` (`200`). However, the test seems to ignore any assertions (`expect()`) and executes successfully.

Comment: You _explicitly catch_ the error from the failing expectation... It's an `async` function; don't mix `.then` and `.catch` in.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, thanks for correcting me. However, if test fails how I can handle response.error if I have only .then (for positive result). I would like to cover both scenarios if test passes it will be checked in then() if not I need to check response error thoroughly